# mvc 5 DataVisualization charting wrong dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, charts

I am using the following to generate a chart:

```
 private Byte[] myChart()
    {
        var query = from o in db.charttest
                    group o by new { o.Date, o.Value }
             into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Value = g.Key.Value,
                        Date = g.Key.Date,
                        Number = g.Count()
                    };
        var chart = new Chart
        {
            Width = 700,
            Height = 450,
            RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag,
            AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All,
            TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High
        };
        chart.Titles.Add("Summary");
        chart.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Arial", 16f);
        chart.ChartAreas.Add("");
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Date";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Value";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 12f);
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 12f);
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 10f);
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.White;
        chart.Series.Add("");
        chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        foreach (var q in query)
        {
            var Name = q.Value;
            var Day = q.Date;
             chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(Day, Name);
        }
        using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())
        {
            chart.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            return chartimage.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
```

Although I only have three values in the table:

[image]

I get wrong dates:

[image]

I am using EF 6.1. Can't figure out how I can display only the correct dates on AxisX.

Comment: Which charts are you using?

Comment: I am using DataVisualization.Charting.

Comment: if you convert the x-value to string you get your 3 datapoints labeled with the dates. but be aware that strings can't be arranged/sorted on an the x-axis like DateTime,so if you add the latest date first, the first datapoint will be labeled with the latest date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tamwe. I changed

```
Date = g.Key.Date.ToString()
```

Now The chart display the correct dates on the X Axis.